# Android Volley Post StringRequest ServerError

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to connect my app with an API that works fine in POSTMAN but not in my Android APP.

This is my code. I have internet permission and internet in my device. The url and the parameters are fine too.

```
void loginTask()
{

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = URLS.url_login;
    pd = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    pd.setMessage("Ingresando");
    pd.show();
    app.L("url : "+url);

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    app.L(response);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    app.LE("error => "+error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {

        public String getBodyContentType()
        {
            return "application/json";
        }


        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return params;
        }


        // this is the relevant method
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody()
        {
            return getJSONBody().toString().getBytes();
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);


}

private String getJSONBody()
{
    JSONObject body = null;
    try
    {
        body = new JSONObject();
        body.put(URLS.param_username,editText_user.getText().toString());
        body.put(URLS.param_pass,editText_pass.getText().toString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return body;
}
```

This is the error

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://200.51.42.196:11440/stocktaller/public_html/client/login

com.android.volley.ServerError
 at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:163)
at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

Any help ? Thanks a lot! I will try other solutions

**UPDATE: I try JSONRequest with the same results**

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, getJSONBody(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
                app.L(response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
                error.printStackTrace();
                app.LE("error => "+error.toString());
            }
        })
        {
            public String getBodyContentType()
            {
                return "application/json";
            }


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: Can you give us the constant value of `URLS.param_username` and `URLS.param_pass`? So that we can test.

Comment: public static String param_username = "username";
    public static String param_pass = "password";

Comment: And can you provide a correct username and password for the sake of the testing? So far it is working.

Comment: {
 "username": "Usuario",
 "password": "Usua1234"
}

Comment: In Android its working ?

Comment: Yes it is working for me, BTW you dont need to overide `getHeaders()` and `getBodyContentType()`. If I loggin the correct username it goes to `onResponse` but If I login a wrong user/pass it goes to `onErrorResponse`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131533/discussion-between-benoffi7-and-user12312313).

Comment: Now the API returns 200 and the code is just fine

Comment: Good to hear :)